# Is assignment of std::array from braced list of values allowed in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, language-lawyer

In c++ primer(5th Edition), it is mentioned that std::array assignment from braced list of values is not allowed.

> Because the size of the right-hand operand might differ from the size
>   of the left-hand operand, the array type does not support assign and
>   it does not allow assignment from a braced list of values.

Below code is given as an example.

```
  std::array<int, 10> a1 = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}; 
  std::array<int, 10> a2 = {0}; // elements all have value 0
  a1 = a2; // replaces elements in a1
  a2 = {0}; // error: cannot assign to an array from a braced list
```

However, when I compile this [code](https://repl.it/@KumarSourav/array) with c++11 compiler it works fine. Is this allowed now or am I missing something?

Comment: Do you read the C++ primer edition form 2012 which was rewritten to take into account c++11 ?  Or still an old and obsolete version ?

Comment: When you compile with c++11 it works fine? So what standard do you use if you don't use c++11? C++98?

Comment: @Christophe - c++11 primer 5th edition

Comment: @JVApen - use c++11..

Answer (score 4):

Yes, a `std::array` can be assigned from a braced list. It just works normally under C++11 rules - the class doesn't have to do anything special to support it. [Consider](https://rextester.com/OXSEO68036):

```
struct S {int x; int y;};
int main() {
  S s{1, 2};
  s = {3, 4};
}
```

Being an aggregate, `S` can be constructed from brace-init list. Further, `S` has an implicitly declared assignment operator taking `const S&`. Putting the two together, the compiler interprets `s = {3, 4}` as `s.operator=(S{3, 4})`

The same happens with `std::array`.

Comment: But does this really explain that you can write `std::array<int, 10> a = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};  a = {1};`?  (And that then `a[0]` is `1` and  `a[1]` ...   `a[9]` is `0`?). And the `std::array<int, 10> a2 = {0}; // elements all have value 0` of the book is also misleading. `std::array<int, 10> a2 = {1};` would result in the first element to be `1` and all remaining to be `0`.

Comment: So, the book is wrong then ? or this feature got added later ?

Comment: @t.niese *"But does this really explain..."* Yes, I believe it does. What specifically do you feel remains unclear?

Comment: @bornfree I'm not familiar with this particular book. If in fact it says that `a2 = {0};` should not be accepted by a C++11-conforming compiler, then it's mistaken, in my opinion.

Comment: Before CWG1270 the book was technically correct for the wrong reason (initializing a `std::array` with `{0}` depends on brace elision, which was not allowed in that context).